# Existence of unit vector field along $\gamma$ everywhere parallel to given analytic vector field

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $\gamma$ be a smooth regular curve $I \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$, and let $X \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a smooth vector field along $\gamma$. Define $E$ to be a *unit* vector field along $\gamma$ such that $E(t) \times X(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$.

I would like to understand under what conditions the vector field $E$ is well-defined, i.e., continuous. I guess that $E$ is continuous if every zero of $X$ is isolated. Am I correct?

Could one prove well-definedness of $E$ under any weaker assumption?

EDIT. As discussed in the comments, the vector field $E$ may fail to exist even if $X$ has isolated zeros. Does assuming that $X$ be analytic make any difference?

Comment: Does $\times$ stand for the cross product ? If it's the case, $E = \pm X$ seems to work.

Comment: @Falcon those $E$'s is not necessarily unit vector fields.

Comment: I don't see how isolated zeroes of $X$ will help. Say $X(0)=0$. If $\lim_{t\to 0^+} X(t)/\|X(t)\| \ne \lim_{t\to 0^-} X(t)/\|X(t)\|$, there is no hope.

Comment: Such $E$ need not exist even if zeroes are isolated.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are saying that, even if $X$ is smooth, $\lim_{t \to 0} \mathrm{span}(X)$ might not exist. Correct?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is somewhat counterintuitive (at least to me). Would requiring that the curve and the vector field be analytic make a difference?

Comment: Probably not, but this assumption would make it harder to find a counter example.

Comment: With smoothness imposed, the only sort of counterexample I can come up with will *fail* to be real analytic. The curve is irrelevant in your question. All that matters is the vector field $X(t)$. Take, for example, $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\le 0\end{cases}.$$ Define $$X(t) = \begin{cases} (f(t),0,0) , & t\ge 0 \\ (0,f(-t),0), & t<0 \end{cases}.$$

Comment: @TedShifrin That's helpful, thanks!